# Question about implementing functions calls in an intrepreter

Tags: interpreter

Consider the pseudo code:

```
function test()
   print ('First Method')

test()
```

When the interpreter reads this code it enters the symbol 'test' into the symbol table then compiles the test() function into bytecode

When it comes to test(), it first looks up test in the symbol table, finds it, and emits code to push that symbol onto the VM stack. It then sees () and emits a 'call' bytecode. We end up with this sequence of calls

```
push test
call
```

What happens if we also have a second test declared in the same scripts such as:

```
function test()
   print ('First Method')

test()

function test()
   print ('Second Method')
```

Byte code:

```
push test
call
push test <- but which test?
```

When the interpreter encounters the second function, it has the same name as the first function, what do we do? If we replace the symbol table entry with the new test function we lose the entry that the test() call was relying on. I noticed that interpreters such as R and Python preserve the call to the original test function.

My question is how is this done? The only way I can think of is that there is some kind of scoping going on. Thus the first function and the call to test() all are in one scope with its own symbol table and the second function is in a separate scope and has its own symbol table. The second scoping would also have to be inside the first scope. For example

```
function test()
   print ('First Method')

test()

x = "This is in the first scope"

function test()
   print ('Second Method')

print (x)
```

The print (x) would first search for the symbol x in the local scope, then in the enclosing scope.

Comment: In languages with these semantics, function names are mutable variables and function definitions are assignments. So you'd handle a redefinition of `test` the same way as a you would a reassignment of any other variable. Incidentally, a user could also write `test = someOtherFunction` or even `test = 42` and subsequent (but not previous) calls to `test()` would be affected by that assignment (in Python and R that is - whether you want your language to behave the same way is up to you of course).

Comment: Agreed that function names act like any other variable. So if I redefine the test variable by declaring a second function with the same name, when the byte code executes and comes across the first test, that test has been reassigned to the second function. But that's not the behavior I see in python or R.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - why would it have been reassigned to the second function if you call `test()` *before* said reassignment? When you run `x = 42; print(x); x = 23` in Python, this will print 42, not 23, right? Similarly if you write `f = lambda: print(42); f(); f = lambda: print(23)`, it will still print 42. And if you replace the lambda assignment with a `def`, it will still print 42 because, in essence, a `def` isn't any different than assigning a lambda (except that you can't write everything as a lambda in Python).

Comment: I looked at the python bytecode on how it handles functions and I see that python relates the function object to the symbol name at runtime using the MAKE_FUNCTION opcode.

Comment: Your simple example: "When you run x = 42; print(x); x = 23 in Python, this will print 42, not 23, right? " is making me think because function variables should behave in the same way. . Although I thought was treating them like any other variables it seems I'm not. I will think about this problem.

Comment: "However, when it assembles the byte code, the second f = lambda: print (23), will overwrite the symbol table entry for the first lambda" Assignments shouldn't overwrite symbol table entries (if they did, the `x=42; print(x); x=23` example would end up printing 23), they should translate to stores that are executed at runtime. The symbol table just tells us where the assignment should store the assigned value (and potentially other static information like types in the case of statically typed languages).

Comment: I want to say thanks for your help, you got me thinking in the right way about the problem and I've resolved the issue.